# What is different each IE 11 on Windows 7 and 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, website, web

If some website is compatible with **IE 11** on Windows **7**, then is it safe to make sure that compatible with **IE 11** on Windows **10**?

As a web-service provider, I have tested on Windows 7. But not sure for there's no problem on Windows 10.

Wonder if there are any differences between them and something I have to care.

Comment: As far as I know both should pretty much support the same software and services. In fact, Internet explorer is installed by default for exact that compatibility. It is installed for older technologys to work. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt156988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The IE version numbers are different for W7 vs W10, W10 is currently 11.0.10240.16431, W7 is currently 11.0.9600.18015, what the exact differences are is anyone guess as it is closed source software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that my development team has recently completed regression testing out web based product on windows 10 / ie 11 and everything was fine.